# jQuery .on() method fails with bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, onclick, radio-button

I have two radio buttons that worked perfectly fine before including bootstrap into my page. I'm not sure why bootstrap would interfere with a simple .on() jQuery method... It is driving me crazy because I've tried various other methods like onClick and it also didn't work.

**The bootstrap library I've included:**

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**The jQuery used for testing that worked before including Bootstrap:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#button2').on('click', function () {
        alert('it works!');
    });

    $('#button1').on('click', function () {
        alert('it works!');
    });
});
```

**Testing HTML:**

```
<div class='btn-group oneLine' data-toggle='buttons'>
    <label class='btn btn-primary'>
        <input type='radio' name='options' id='button1' autocomplete='off'> <a class='test'>Button 1</a>
    </label>

    <label class='btn btn-primary'>
        <input type='radio' name='options' id='button2' autocomplete='off' checked> <a class='test'>Button 2</a>
    </label>
</div>
```

**I've added the code for live testing below (without bootstrap included):**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#button2').on('click', function () {
    alert('it works!');
  });

  $('#button1').on('click', function () {
    alert('it works!');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='btn-group oneLine' data-toggle='buttons'>
  <label class='btn btn-primary'>
    <input type='radio' name='options' id='button1' autocomplete='off'> <a class='test'>Button 1</a>
  </label>

  <label class='btn btn-primary'>
    <input type='radio' name='options' id='button2' autocomplete='off' checked> <a class='test'>Button 2</a>
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm not sure why bootstrap would interfere with a simple .on() jQuery method...

That happens because "boostrap" adds the following two styles for each radio input element:

> - [clip: rect(0,0,0,0)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip): the clip CSS property defines what portion of an element is visible.
> - [pointer-events: none](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events): The CSS property pointer-events allows authors to control under what circumstances (if any) a particular graphic element can become the target of mouse events.

Now, you have two strategy: remove these two styles or consider another approach.

Your radio button is contained inside a label. Each click event is captured from the label or anchor and nothing is passed to the radio button.

This means that the event handler must be attached to the label:

```
$('#button2').closest('.btn')
```

You may reduce the lines of code using [Attribute Starts With Selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) and [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).

An alternative way is to use directly the label.

The snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('[id^="button"]').closest('.btn').on('click', function () {
    console.log(this.querySelector('input').id + ': it works!');
  });

  $('div.btn-group.oneLine label.btn').on('click', function () {
    console.log('An alternative way is to use the label: ' + this.querySelector('input').id + ': it works!');
  });

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class='btn-group oneLine' data-toggle='buttons'>
    <label class='btn btn-primary'>
        <input type='radio' name='options' id='button1' autocomplete='off'> <a class='test'>Button 1</a>
    </label>

    <label class='btn btn-primary'>
        <input type='radio' name='options' id='button2' autocomplete='off' checked> <a class='test'>Button 2</a>
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow! Fantastic answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: @theflarenet Answer updated: I hope now it's clear the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you should include bootstrap js AFTER jquery one. See example [here](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template). Also check jquery version compatibility, in your example you are using 2.2.1 but in bootstrap 1.12.